# How to delete file if the row of table data had deleted in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to delete file if the row of table data had deleted in laravel?

**code**:

```
 public function destroy($id)
 {
    
    $customer = customer::find($id);
   
    $exist_image=$customer->prooffile;
   
    if (isset($exist_image) && file_exists($exist_image)) {

        unlink($exist_image);
    }
    $customer->delete();

    return $this->index();


}
```

I Think `file_exists()` not working here any better way to delete the file in public folder.

Comment: may i know what issue are you facing now ? and also where you storing files

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or a clear problem description. If you _think_ something isn't working properly then the first thing you need to do is go and debug it, so that you can be more certain. Have you done that?

Comment: i have  already stored file in public/ userfiles/proof/filename   if i  want delete file the appropriate file should deleted in publuc/userfiles/proof/filename in this path and table also

Comment: check your public path of uploaded image, because file_exists works perfectly.and what's issue occurs in this syntex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `$exist_image` return only `image name` then

```
$customer = customer::find($id);
if(! $customer){
abort(403);
}
   $exist_image=$customer->prooffile;
    if(File::exists(public_path('userfiles/proof/'.$exist_image))) {
                        
     File::delete(public_path('userfiles/proof/'.$exist_image));
     $customer->prooffile=null;
     $customer->save();
    }
```

Import right facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run filepath through [realpath](https://www.php.net/realpath), secondly check if the returned path is [writable](https://www.php.net/is_writable) and if so, [unlink](https://www.php.net/unlink) it.